# JAXB unmarshalling schema issues: 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException cvc-elt.1'

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Having not worked with XML schemas in many years, I'm having problems manually unmarshalling some XML with a schema generated in XML Spy.

For the life of me I cannot resolve it despite various other google'd questions/responses of similar ilk!

Here's the XML (vastly reduced just to highlight the issue):

```
<myelement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./myxsd.xsd">
</myelement>
```

Here's the myxsd.xsd schema (vastly reduced just to highlight the issue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://myhost.com/Elements" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" targetNamespace="http://myhost.com/Elements" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="myelement"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Here's the code:

```
String xml = ""; //input the XML from above.
JAXBContext context =
    JAXBContext.newInstance(MyElement.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

document = (MyElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

And the element pojo:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myelement", namespace = "http://myhost.com/Elements")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
@XmlType(name = "myelementType", namespace = "http://myhost.com/Elements")
public class MyElement {
}
```

Resulting in:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 110; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element ‘myelement’.]
```

Comment: Are your XMLs strings in the actual code? Any reason to not just feed the file to unmarhsal()?

Comment: This is just example code, however the XML is passed in it will still result in the same error. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that a space is present ‘my element’. Check myxsd.xsd file

Comment: Thank  you but there doesn't seem to be a space there?

Comment: Then the message Cannot find the declaration of element ‘my element’. is weird because it looks like there is a space. Maybe debugging where Sax fails could be of some help

Comment: Ah apologies; I hadn't realised you meant in the error - this was just me copy and pasting then editing the error for the sake of making the classes anonymous etc, the space shouldn't be there and I've updated the error. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Is the XSD accessible ? maybe JAx cannot fetch it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MyElement unmarshal(String str) throws JAXBException {
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyElement.class);
 Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

 JAXBElement<MyElement> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(str))), MyElement.class);
 MyElement el = root.getValue();

 return el;
}
```

Maybe something like the above.